# Does ngIf allow to set div visibility only once? Or does it also allow to toggle?

Tags: angular6, angular-ng-if

I set this test case where I have two `div` elements. I want to make one them visible based on the user selection in the `drop-down <select>`. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-m8awhb

However, it seems like `ngIf` works correctly only `onInit`. But then when user toggles the `drop-down <select>` multiple times , `ngIf` retains the original value.

Does `ngIf` allow to toggle in Angular 6? I remember it was okay in AngularJS

Comment: Whenver the variable assigned to NgIf changes, so would the state of ngIf.  If you are thinking that you are setting the variable, i wish to remind you of scopes.   `isVisible` is not necessarily pointing to the variable addressed in scope `this.isVisible`

Comment: Thank you. Then how can I fix it?

Comment: you would create a function in the javascript which changes it and execute it somehow.  `function toggle() { this.isVisible = !this.isVisible; }` is a simple solution.

Comment: I used jquery toggle() . but i was under impression Angular should make these things built in. Angular original presentation they wer showing when typing in one field, value gets displayed in another `{{value}}`

Comment: I was not referencing the jquery Toggle function, just defined my own.  You need to leverage some sort of event to call a function which would toggle the state of `isVisible`.